# Por que o BroadcastReceiver é chamado várias vezes e sempre com o mesmo "extra"?

Tags: android, intent, broadcastreceiver

Tenho um aplicativo que envia sms em android, e um Broadcast para capturar os erros caso não consigo enviar ao destinatário.
 Caso não consiga enviar uma mensagem, eu capturo o objeto e gravo no banco de dados com o tipo do erro que ocorreu, para envio posterior.

O método funciona perfeitamente se eu enviar um por vez, porém eu efetuei uma bateria de testes aonde tenho mais de 50 mensagens para envio por vez, e o método sempre me retorna o último objeto da lista dos que deram erro.

Exemplo, se eu enviar os seguintes sms, e desabilitar o modo avião para simular um erro, nessa ordem:

1 - Destinatário A

2 - Destinatário B

3 - Destinatário C

4 - Destinatário D

O Broadcast grava 4 vezes no banco de dados o elemento 4.

Eu passo o objeto atráves de Extras da Intent, quando crio o Broadcast, e recupero no código abaixo.

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {

    if (naoEnviadoDao == null) {
        naoEnviadoDao = ORMLiteHelper.getInstance(ctx).getNaoEnviadosDao();
    }
   //Recupero o objeto passado como parâmetro no envio
   //Se eu mandar um sms por vez, funciona, mas se for mais 3-4 por exemplo, sempre grava o último n vezes.
    NaoEnviado naoEnviado = (NaoEnviado) intent.getSerializableExtra("naoEnviado");
    if (!naoEnviados.contains(naoEnviado)) {
        naoEnviados.add(naoEnviado);
    }
    switch (getResultCode()) {
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
            naoEnviado.setTipoFalha("Falha genérica.");
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
            naoEnviado.setTipoFalha("Sem serviço.");
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
            naoEnviado.setTipoFalha("Falha no Provedor PDU.");
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
            naoEnviado.setTipoFalha("Modo avião ativo.");
            break;
    }

    if (naoEnviado.getTipoFalha() != null &&
            !naoEnviado.getTipoFalha().equals("")) {
        try {
            naoEnviadoDao.create(naoEnviado);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        naoEnviado = new NaoEnviado();
    }
}
```

Outro detalhe que eu constatei em testes, é que se eu por um Thread.sleep de 6 segundos por exemplo, ele grava certo, porém tenho situações que eu preciso enviar mais de 200 sms por vez, o que acaba deixando a tela travada, alguém tem uma ideia do que possa ser?

//Código que registro os Broadcast

```
 public void sendSMS(final String mensagem, final String nomeParceiro, String telefone) {
        //Remove caracteres do cel e formata a msg antes de enviar...
        Telefone tel = new Telefone(ctx);
        final String celular = tel.formataTelefone(telefone);
        final String msg = mensagem.replace("%nome%", nomeParceiro.substring(0,
                nomeParceiro.indexOf(" ") > 0 ? nomeParceiro.indexOf(" ") : nomeParceiro.length()));

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(msg);
        int messageCount = parts.size();

        ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

        NaoEnviado naoEnviado = new NaoEnviado();
        naoEnviado.setMensagem(msg);
        naoEnviado.setNome(nomeParceiro);
        naoEnviado.setTelefone(celular);

        Intent itSent = new Intent(SENT);
        itSent.putExtra("naoEnviado", naoEnviado);

        Intent itDelivery = new Intent(DELIVERED);
        itDelivery.putExtra("naoEnviado", naoEnviado);

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, itSent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, itDelivery,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        for (int j = 0; j < messageCount; j++) {
            sentIntents.add(sentPI);
            deliveryIntents.add(deliveredPI);
        }

        //Registra os receiver de envio e recebimento
        ((Activity) ctx).registerReceiver(SentReceiver.getInstance(),
                new IntentFilter(SENT));

        ((Activity) ctx).registerReceiver(DeliveredReceiver.getInstance(),
                new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

        sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(tel.removeCaracteres(celular),
                null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents);
    }
```

Encontrei duas soluções possíveis:

1) Se quiser passar um Objeto como parâmetro, depois do método sendMultipartTextMessage, adicionei uma pausa de 6 segundos, e o método passou a funcionar, não é uma solução elegante, mas resolveu.

```
//Envia o SMS
    sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(telefone, null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(6000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
```

2) Ao invés de passar Um objeto como parâmetro, eu passei uma String, e recuperei no OnReceive() como getStringExtra(), desse jeito funcionou sem mais problemas.

```
//OnReceive
```

String aux = intent.getStringExtra("obj");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse comportamento tem duas causas:

- O *BroadcastReceveir* está a ser chamado várias vezes porque ele está ser registado por cada mensagem enviada.
- O facto de ser tratado apenas o último se deve a que, quando é solicitado um PendingIntent, o sistema verifica se já existe algum anteriormente criado e, se forem usados dois *Intent* equivalentes<sup>(1)</sup>, conforme [Intent.filterEquals](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals%28android.content.Intent%29), o mesmo PendingIntent é retornado para ambos.

  A *flag* passada no último parâmetro permite "ajustar" esse comportamento:

  Ao passar [FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) 
  indicamos que, se o PendingIntent já existe, ele é mantido tendo os seus *extra* substituídos pelos do novo *Intent*.
  Isto é útil quando apenas se quer tratar uma vez o *Intent* com os *Extra* mais recentes.

A primeira resolve-se registando os *BroadcastReceveir* no `onResume()` e "desregistando" no `onPause()`.

Para resolver a segunda temos de garantir que, ou os *Intent* usados para obter o PendingIntent são diferentes<sup>(2)</sup>, alterando um dos aspectos considerados pelo *Intent.filterEquals*, ou o segundo parâmetro passado ao método `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` é diferente do anterior.

Assim, em vez de passar `0` no segundo parâmetro, altere o código de forma a que, ao solicitar o *PendingIntent*, seja utilizado um valor diferente em cada chamada, por exemplo `(int)System.currentTimeMillis();`.

<sub><sup>(1)</sup>Eles são equivalentes quando a *action*, *data*, *type*, *class*, e *categories* são as mesmas. Não são levados em conta os *extra*.</sub>

<sub><sup>(2)</sup>Uma forma possível é definir a *data* desta forma: `itSent.setData(Uri.parse(itSent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));`</sub>

<sub>`itSent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)` converte o *Intent* em uma *String* contendo a sua representação no formato URI com um *Schema* igual a "intent".

Pelos testes efectuados só funciona em cujos *extras* sejam tipos primitivos. Com tipos Parcelable ou Serializable os *Intent* foram considerados equivalentes.</sub>

Comment: Exatamente isso, deu um pouco de trabalho encontrar a solução, mas foi solucionado, muito obrigado pela ajuda @ramaral

Comment: Você reparou que  a solução passa por usar um valor diferente no segundo parâmetro de `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`?

Comment: Sim, porém pra mim eu só necessito passar o número de telefone pela Intent por parâmetro, no caso uma String, ao invés de passar o id como requestcode, o simples fato de usar tipos primitivos também resolveu o problema.

Comment: Por isso é que nos meus teste o uso de setData() funcionava e com você não. No meu teste usava uma string como extra!

Comment: Sim, exatamente, fui perceber o problema, quando refiz o código e usei um for, sendo i como extra, o mesmo exemplo que você testou, e deu certo. depois só adaptei o meu código com isso.